# How to give notification message to the currently logged in users using c#

Tags: c#, sockets, browser, client-server

We are creating a new socket for the currently logged in user asynchronously.The server will notify this user at appropriate time then a pop up message should occur to the users who might be in different view page. we are creating socket like:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0,
                  new AsyncCallback(ReceiveNotification), socket);


private void ReceiveNotification(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    socket.EndReceive(ar);

    //Need to perform notification stuff here                 
    socket.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try https://github.com/SignalR, it allows notify all open clients and maintain transport level so you don't need to care about sockets etc.